# Trouble getting cakephp 2.4.0 running - fatal errors when attempting to complete tutorial

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am trying to follow the instructions for the cakephp tutorial found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html

I uploaded the CakePHP files to my webserver, created the database using MySQL workbench, and created database.php and updated it to point to my MySQL server.

At this point it sounds like I should be able to open up the website in my browser and see something, but instead I get these errors (I have removed the full path):

```
Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in /caketut/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 325

Warning: caketut/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /www/premium/med/pediatrics/www.hobmt.umn.edu/htdocs/caketut/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 380

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /caketut/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:181
Stack trace:
#0 /caketut/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(151): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_')
#1 /caketut/app/Config/core.php(367): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array)
#2 /caketut/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(72): include('/www/premium/me...')
#3 /caketut/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(177): Configure::bootstrap(true)
#4 /caketut/app/webroot/index.php(92): include('/www/premium/me...')
#5 {main} thrown in /caketut/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181
```

I tried setting the permissions for the Cache folder located in /caketut/lib/Cake and all subfolders/files to be 0776, and this removes all errors except this one:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cache' not found in /caketut/app/Config/core.php on line 361
```

I tried doing searches but was unsuccessful in finding a solution. I would really appreciate any assistance!

Comment: well this is embarrassing. I replaced the Cache folder and files because I figured I broke them somehow, then I changed the permissions of caketuto/app/tmp to 0777, and although I got similar errors for the first few refreshes it seems to be working now. I know I should set the owner of that folder to be the web server, but I'm not sure how to do this in WinSCP.

Answer (score 1):

try to chmod the whole script with 0777 permissions .

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 caketut
```